# OnScroll doesn't send any events on android when using react-native-swiper

Tags: android, react-native, swiper.js, onscroll

Using this [react-native-swiper](https://github.com/leecade/react-native-swiper) Module with the following code:

```
<Swiper
      loop={false}
      showsPagination={false}
      onScroll={Animated.event(
        [{ nativeEvent: { contentOffset: { x: this.state.left } }}],
        {
          listener: event => {
            console.log(event);
          }
        }
      )}
      scrollEventThrottle={1}
    >
```

won't send any event to the console on android and for so won't animate the UI as needed.

Here you can see the UI on iOS and Android:
http://g.recordit.co/cSGBgpAmfl.gif

Any ideas?